# How to implement a simple event emitter style publisher in Combine?

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

So I'm getting started with Combine, and I want to have a component which publishes events like a simple event emitter.

So in other words, I want to have a model like this (pseudocode):

```
class MyModel {
   var onNewEvent: EventPublisher

   func foo(bar: Bar) {
       onNewEvent.publish(Event(bar))
   }
}

let model: MyModel...

model.onNewEvent.sink(
    receiveValue: { event in print(event) }
)
```

I can achieve something like this using a notification center publisher, but I want to avoid this unnecessary step if possible.

Is there such a thing as a simple publisher which just publishes values on command, or else what would be the idiomatic way to handle this in combine?

Comment: You are looking for a [Subject](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/subject)

Comment: Yes, or a @Published.

Comment: You just need `PassthroughSubject`.

Comment: See my https://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/publishers/publishers.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use a `private`(outside world cannot change/emit values) `subject` inside your model. and then expose it using a `lazy publisher` to let the outside world to subscribe.

```swift
class MyModel {
    private var myPassthroughSubject = PassthroughSubject<Bar, Never>() // make this subject `private`, so only inside methods can send values.
    lazy var myPublisher = myPassthroughSubject.eraseToAnyPublisher() // expose this publisher to the outside world.
    
    func foo(bar: Bar) {
        myPassthroughSubject.send(bar)
    }
}

struct Bar {
    
}

let model = MyModel()

model.myPublisher.sink(
    receiveValue: { event in print(event) }
)

model.foo(bar: .init())
model.foo(bar: .init())
```

Comment: Pure code answers are rarely useful.

Comment: agree! added some explanation too!